# Макросы в C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Я определяю функцию как макрос:

```
#define DIVIDE(x, y) x / y
```

и вызываю ее в коде:

```
z = DIVIDE(1 + 1, 1 + 1);
```

в результате получаю:

```
z = 3;
```

а должно быть:

```
z = 1;
```

В чем причина?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что макроопределение

```
#define DIVIDE(x, y) x / y
```

при вызове

```
z = DIVIDE(1 + 1, 1 + 1);
```

раскрывается препроцессором в выражение

```
z = 1 + 1/1 + 1;
```

что и дает

```
z = 3;
```

Сначала макрос раскрывается, а затем вычисляется, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что вы неправильно используете макросы.

1. Содержимое макроса берите в скобки.
2. Все аргументы берите в скобки.

Тогда макросы будут исполняться правильно:

```
#define DIVIDE(x, y) ((x) / (y))
```

Получите результат:

```
z = DIVIDE(1 + 1, 1 + 1) = ((1 + 1) / (1 + 1)) = (2 / 2) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

И вообще - лучше макросами не пользоваться, а определить свою шаблонную функцию для деления.

```
template <class Type>
Type my_divide(Type x, Type y)
{
  return x / y;
}
```

Практически наверняка эта ф-ция будет встроенной, так что накладные расходы на ее вызов будут минимальны. А заодно не будет минусов, присущих макросам.